# How to condition a variable so that it takes all values within IN clause

Tags: mysql

I'm very hesitant and I have not gotten solutions, so I turn here.
Quickly explain, suppose I want to filter a query as follows:

```
SELECT name FROM students WHERE courseCode IN (17, 18, 19);
```

Here I will get the students who are enrolled in courses 17 **or** 18 **or** 19.

Now, how would you get the students who are enrolled in those 3 courses? That is, in 17 **and** 18 **and** 19?

Maybe it can be simple when you know what the "courseCode" values are, but how would you do it when you get those values with a subquery?

Something like this:

```
SELECT name FROM students WHERE courseCode = 17 and courseCode = 18 and courseCode = 19;
```

when I know the values (This is not correct)

but how would I do when I do not know what values they are? Like this:

```
SELECT name FROM students WHERE courseCode IN (SELECT courseCode FROM course WHERE ...);
```

I hope you have explained me well, thanks for your help

Comment: I believe you can use the `ALL` condition here. Just swap out that `IN` and let it ride. [more info here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/all-subqueries.html)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one possible way to do it, collapsing with a GROUP BY and getting a count of distinct coursecode, and comparing that to a literal:

```
 SELECT s.name
   FROM students s 
  WHERE s.courseCode IN (17,18,19)
  GROUP BY s.name
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s.courseCode) = 3
```

The `(17,18,19)` could be replaced by a subquery. But I would tend to use an inline view and a join operation.

```
 SELECT s.name
   FROM students s
   JOIN ( SELECT 17 AS courseCode
           UNION ALL SELECT 18
           UNION ALL SELECT 19
        ) c
     ON c.courseCode = s.courseCode
  GROUP BY s.name
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s.courseCode) = 3
```

The query for inline view `c` just needs to return distinct values of a column named `courseCode` with appropriate datatype... a lot of possible queries will work ...

```
   JOIN ( SELECT foo AS courseCode 
            FROM bar 
           WHERE ... 
           GROUP BY foo
        ) c
```

This is an example of one approach, there are other approaches...